# matplotlib: plot a line iterating over dataframe rows

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

in the toy example dataFrame there are 2 sets of coordinates: x, y and ex, ey.

```
d = {'x': [1, 2, 3, 4], 'y': [3, 3, 3, 3], 'ex': [1, 2, 3, 4], 'ey': [6, 6, 6, 6]}
toy = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
```

Each set needs to be first scatter plotted, then connected by a line.

```
plt.scatter(toy['x'],toy['y'], color='b')
plt.scatter(toy['ex'],toy['ey'], color='g')
plt.plot(toy['x'],toy['y'], color='b')
plt.plot(toy['ex'],toy['ey'], color='g')
```

Finally, samples between sets occurring in the same row have to be connected, also by lines. This was achieved by taking each column as a pandas.Series type

```
x = toy['x']
ex = toy['ex']
y = toy['y']
ey = toy['ey']
```

and iterating over them in a plot function

```
for i in range(len(x)):
    plt.plot([x[i], ex[i]], [y[i], ey[i]], color='cyan')
```

and it worked.

The problem is, when the real dataFrame is taken, this exact approach doesn't work and returns the following error:

---

```
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-174-aa1b4849722f> in <module>()
     21 
     22 for i in range(len(x)):
---> 23     plt.plot([x[i], ex[i]], [y[i], ey[i]], color='cyan')
     24 
     25 plt.show()

/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pandas/core/series.py in __getitem__(self, key)
    601         key = com._apply_if_callable(key, self)
    602         try:
--> 603             result = self.index.get_value(self, key)
    604 
    605             if not is_scalar(result):

/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pandas/indexes/base.py in get_value(self, series, key)
   2167         try:
   2168             return self._engine.get_value(s, k,
-> 2169                                           tz=getattr(series.dtype, 'tz', None))
   2170         except KeyError as e1:
   2171             if len(self) > 0 and self.inferred_type in ['integer', 'boolean']:

pandas/index.pyx in pandas.index.IndexEngine.get_value (pandas/index.c:3557)()

pandas/index.pyx in pandas.index.IndexEngine.get_value (pandas/index.c:3240)()

pandas/index.pyx in pandas.index.IndexEngine.get_loc (pandas/index.c:4279)()

pandas/src/hashtable_class_helper.pxi in pandas.hashtable.Int64HashTable.get_item (pandas/hashtable.c:8564)()

pandas/src/hashtable_class_helper.pxi in pandas.hashtable.Int64HashTable.get_item (pandas/hashtable.c:8508)()

KeyError: 0
```

Anybody knows what did I do wrong? It confuses me much, as this approach did work for the toy example.

Many thanks in advance and I hope the problem was stated clearly enough (newbie here).

Comment: What do you get if you `print(x)` in your real dataFrame (or at least the first few rows)?

Comment: The error might be happening becuase the index of your dataFrame is not what you expect i.e. doesn't start at 0

Comment: List of index/values pairs, dtype: float64.

Comment: riiiiight, it doesn't

Comment: I did reset_index now works like a charm. many many thanks!

Comment: No problem :-) If you feel like it, you could put what you did as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

Okay, so in the real dataFrame only a subset of data was selected for plotting. 
Thus, the subset's index did not begin with 0, which apparently confused Python.
The solution was to reset the index using:

```
df = df.reset_index(drop=True)
```

Thanks for help :)